# Scroll to a section of the page when clicking on the navbar

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I've been making my first website - a single page site with different sections containing content. I've created a nice looking navbar and have been scouring the internet to try and find a way to add functionality to it.

Here is the markup of the navbar:

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">    
        <h3>Stewart Ehoff</h3>
    </div>    
    <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
      <img src="images/shield.svg">
    </a>   

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#myskills">My Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mywork">My Work</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#exploration">Exploration</a></li>
          <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your page on github and added ID's to your content. If you do for example:  then you will go to a container with id="id".

For example with your page i added:

```
<li><a href="#myskills">My Skills</a></li>
```

with the HTML

```
<div id="myskills">
```

Here is the full HTML.

```js
//More Menu Dropdown Toggle Function

var main = function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();

  });
  //Next Arrow Functionality    
  $('.arrow-next').click(function() {

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

  });
  //Previous Arrow Click Functionality
  $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }


    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');

  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
/* General */

.container {
  width: 960px;
}
.underline {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7FCCE5;
}
.underlinegrey {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
}
.underlineblack {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #313131;
}
.underlinethin {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7FCCE5;
}
.circle-icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  4 line-height: 80px;
  font-size 2.1em;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.circle-icon .glyphicon {
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Nav Bar */

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav .title {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: -10px;
}
.logo-icon {
  position: fixed;
  left: 500px;
  top: 8px;
}
/* Menu */

.nav .menu {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.menu > li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #898989;
}
.menu .border a {
  border: 1px solid #7FCCE5;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
/* Dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 105px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #898989;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
/* Jumbotron */

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/58/1822942.jpg');
  height: 1020px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: initial;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.jumbotron p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.jumbotron h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color: #f7f6f6;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f7f6f6;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 340px;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #f7f6f6;
}
/* About Me */

.about {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.about .container {
  top: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
.about h3 {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding;
  20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.about p {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 30px;
  line-height: 210%;
}
/* My Skills  */

.myskills {
  height: 880px;
  background-color: #F7F6F6;
}
.myskills .container {
  width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
.myskills .row {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.myskills h3 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}
.myskills h1 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.myskills p {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding;
  20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
}
.glyphicon-heart {
  color: red;
}
.glyphicon-picture {
  color: orange;
}
.glyphicon-cloud {
  color: white;
}
.glyphicon-camera {
  color: black;
}
.glyphicon-book {
  color: darkviolet;
}
.glyphicon-music {
  color: orangered;
}
/* My Work */

.mywork {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.mywork .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
.mywork h3 {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.mywork h1 {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.mywork p {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Contact */

.contact {
  height: 330px;
  background-color: #313131;
}
.contact .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
.contact .row {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 325px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.contact h3 {
  color: #F7F6F6;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding;
  20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact h1 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact p {
  color: #F7F6F6;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact a {
  color: #7FCCE5;
}
/* Exploration */

.exploration {
  height: 1100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.exploration .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  width: 1200px;
}
.exploration h3 {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.exploration p {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
.slide {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.active-slide {
  display: block;
}
/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  height: 800px;
}
.slide-feature-1 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/11036160_10152854777396270_5157414753497878003_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}
.slide-feature-2 {
  background-image: url('https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t31.0-8/11218515_10152909922431270_7749144937209461633_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}
.slide-feature-3 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/11187795_10152891725491270_1769195601160147349_o.jpg');
  background-position: bottom;
}
.slide-feature-4 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/11154672_10152854784061270_3532862830070230799_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}
.slide-feature-5 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/11164749_10152909922426270_8192461025609874418_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}
.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}
.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #7FCCE5;
}
/*Music*/

.music {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: #313131;
}
.music .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  width: 1500px;
}
.music h3 {
  color: #F7F6F6;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: ;
  40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.music h1 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.music p {
  color: #F7F6F6;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-;
  text-align: center;
}
iframe {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
/* Footer */

.footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #F7F6F6;
}
.footer h1 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
.footer p {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding;
  20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- NAV BAR -->
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Stewart Ehoff</h3>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/images/shield.svg">
      </a>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#myskills">My Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#mywork">My Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="border"><a href="#contactme">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Exploration</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--JUMBOTRON STARTS HERE-->

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
      <p>My name is <b>Stewart Ehoff</b> and I'm a self-taught web developer.</p>
      <h3>Let's work <em>together.</em> </h3>

      <button type="button" class="btn">TELL ME MORE</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn">RESUME</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--JUMBOTRON ENDS HERE-->

  <!--ABOUT STARTS HERE-->

  <div class="about" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underline">About Me</span></h3> 
      <p>I'm a self-taught web developer living in Leicester, United Kingdom. I've been working with technology ever since I was a little boy.</p>
      <p>In 2014, I graduated from De Montfort University with a First Class Honours in Music, Technology and Innovation. Shortly after graduating, I recieved an internship at a professional audio solutions company, and went on to conduct work for companies
        such as Warner Records and Atlantic Records.</p>
      <p>This website is the fruits of my labour, I hope you enjoy it.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--MY SKILLS STARTS HERE-->

  <div class="myskills" id="myskills">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underlineblack">My Skills</span></h3>

      <!--Row 1-->

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Self-taught</h1> 
          <p>Everything I know I've taught myself. I'd like to think that shows a solid level of drive and dedication.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Front end development</h1> 
          <p>Able to create modern, beautifully designed websites with HTML, CSS and JavaScript that feel great to use.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Frameworks and libaries</h1> 
          <p>Confident with popular front-end (Bootstrap, jQuery) and back-end (Ruby on Rails) frameworks and libaries.</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!--Row 2-->

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Photography</h1> 
          <p>Photo taking, editting and asset creation in Adobe Photoshop and Lightroom.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Learning and problem solving</h1> 
          <p>Constantly striving for educational progression, experimenting with new technologies and refining skills. I see a problem as a challenge to learn.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
          </div>
          <h1 class="underlinethin">Audio</h1> 
          <p>Audio engineer trained in building loudspeaker systems, recording, mixing and mastering audio.</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--MY WORK STARTS HERE-->

  <div class="mywork" id="mywork">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underline">My Work</span></h3>
      <h1>Coming <i>soon...</i></h1>
      <p>I am always looking for exciting and innovative projects to work on. If you want to work together, then please <a href="contact">contact me!</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--CONTACT STARTS HERE-->

  <div class="contact" id="contactme">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underlinegrey">Contact Me</span></h3>
      <h1>Send me an email at <a href="#">stewartehoff@gmail.com</a> or find me on:</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/images/github.png">
          <p>Github</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/images/linkedin.png">
          <p>LinkedIn</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--FLIPBOARD STARTS HERE-->

  <!--EDIT SLIDES HERE-->

  <div class="exploration">

    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underline">Exploration</span></h3>
      <p>I love exploring and capturing epic moments on my journeys. Here's some of my favourites from my latest trip across the west coast of America.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

      <!--SLIDE 1 START-->

      <div class="slide active-slide slide-feature slide-feature-1">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--SLIDE 1 END-->

      <!--SLIDE 2 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-2">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--SLIDE 2 END-->

      <!--SLIDE 3 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--SLIDE 3 END-->

      <!--SLIDE 4 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-4">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--SLIDE 4 END-->

      <!--SLIDE 5 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--SLIDE 5 END-->

    </div>

    <!--Slider navigation. Add more "<li class="dot">&bull;</li>" for more slides.-->

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/images/arrow-left.svg">
      </a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ardiaz/Stewart-Ehoff.com/master/images/arrow-right.svg">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--FLIPBOARD ENDS HERE-->

  </div>

  <div class="music">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><span class="underlinegrey">Music</span></h3>
      <h1>In my early teens, I purchased my first drum kit. Now, I'm more than just a drummer, I'm a music producer too. Here are a few tracks from my production portfolio:</h1>

      <!--Obscurity-->

      <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/149734252&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

      <!--Deception-->

      <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/154191965&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

      <!--Circadian-->

      <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/154192672&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

      <!--Transhuman-->

      <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/73625501&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

      <h1>For more of my music, please visit my <a href='#'>SoundCloud</a> profile.</h1>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>A website by Stewart Ehoff</h1>
      <p>I hope you enjoyed visiting my website. Please don't hesitate to contact me, I would <b>love</b> to hear from you!</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thats how you learn ;-) If we all knew everything from the start, sites like stackoverflow wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @zaidra do you mean in the example or on your site? Without javascript you cannot add parameters to the anchor. The anchor will always put the container at the top. If CSS/Javascript moves this container around, it could happen. At any rate this does not appear to be happening for me in the above example.

Comment: This is because your top is fixed. The anchor works correctly, but because your content scrolls behind your top menu the anchor fails. Either you have to push your content down or use jQuery to scroll to that element. This is expected behavior as browser is concerned.

Comment: @Zaidra I updated the example by adding this it is fixed: 
about .container {
  top: 35px;

Comment: Thankyou so much Thomas, you've been a massive help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).scrollTop(100)
```

Eg:

For Home link

```
<li class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

$('.home').click(function(e){
  $(document).scrollTop(100)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use anchor tags `href=#id` of the section.

`<a href="#images">nav</a>`

`<section id="images">....</section>`

when you click on that anchor tag it'll move to the respected section.
is that what you expecting or correct me if I didn't understand your question

Comment: Do I have to define the section using the <section> html tag? All my sections are just defined with <div> tags.

Comment: Nope,you can use any container tag like `div` too works