# Flutter Web : Scroll to specific widget on click

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[image]

In above gif i have simple layout , on left side have iconButton and other side have Container with some color.

I don't know how to scroll to container when i click on iconButton. In javascript/jquery we can use **id** to specific content, then when click of button we can go to specific content depend of **id** using offset [this is the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436429/scroll-to-a-section-of-the-page-when-clicking-on-the-navbar).

How i can do the same thing but in flutter web side ?

#### Layout

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mqHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              if (sizes.checkLayoutBuilder(constraints) == TypeLayout.Mobile)
                SizedBox()
              else
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => '',
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.home,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            tooltip: 'Welcome',
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => '',
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          tooltip: 'Portfolio',
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => '',
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          tooltip: 'Want know about me ?',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                flex: 10,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Container(height: mqHeight, color: Colors.orange),
                      Container(height: mqHeight, color: Colors.indigo),
                      Container(height: mqHeight, color: Colors.lime),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  TypeLayout checkLayoutBuilder(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
    TypeLayout typeLayout;
    if (maxWidth < 600) {
      typeLayout = TypeLayout.Mobile;
    } else if (maxWidth > 600 && maxWidth < 768) {
      typeLayout = TypeLayout.LargeMobile;
    } else if (maxWidth > 768 && maxWidth < 992) {
      typeLayout = TypeLayout.Tablet;
    } else if (maxWidth > 992 && maxWidth < 1200) {
      typeLayout = TypeLayout.Laptop;
    } else if (maxWidth > 1200) {
      typeLayout = TypeLayout.Desktop;
    }
    return typeLayout;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html

Comment: @pskink it's work ! but i have simple another case depend on it . It's possible to detect we has reached the widget when scrolling ? Example on above gif , i default in orange container then i scroll to indigo / lime container, It's possible to detect it ?

Comment: `ensureVisible` returns a `Future` - they dont say anything about it in the official docs but my inner voice tells me that it is completed when scrolling finishes - try it

Comment: what you mean `completed when scrolling` ? as you said , `ensureVisible` return `Future void` and this not give information anymore

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#what-is-a-future

Comment: some test https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kj3ZPW53Jb/

Comment: @pskink yes i already try your code. But i think you miss understanding my new problem, I will explain with gif. https://media.giphy.com/media/I1cTqACB09i6VpVx2L/giphy.gif If you see this gif,i can scroll to specific widget when i click the side navigation, it's perfect what i want. But my new problem is how to detect i already scroll in specific widget then i can change selected widget on side navigation ?  https://media.giphy.com/media/V6Hu48OcmoZG7UmW6t/giphy.gif

Comment: so you need `ScrollController` and add a listener to that controller

Comment: @pskink Thank's for your reference, what i need to fix my problem is 1.How to get position of widget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291245/get-y-position-of-container-on-flutter 2.get position of scroll  3.Listen to scrollController 4. compare if position scroll >= position widget 5. Then do what i need  https://gph.is/g/EvpXjjw

Comment: Are you using `ListView` here in the `gif` which you showed?

Comment: SinglechildScrollview + Column

Comment: Hello @ZeffryReynando can you please share the code snippet of how you have achieved this?